# Creating database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to allow a user to create a database given information, so to that end, I have the following:

```
<?php
    //ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
    if(isset($_POST['siteName'])) {
        $DBS = htmlspecialchars($_POST['databaseServer']);
        $DBN = htmlspecialchars($_POST['databaseName']);
        $DBU = htmlspecialchars($_POST['databaseUser']);
        $DBP = htmlspecialchars($_POST['databasePass']);
        $SN = htmlspecialchars($_POST['siteName']);
        $AU = htmlspecialchars($_POST['adminUser']);
        $AP = htmlspecialchars($_POST['adminPass']);
        $con = new Mysqli($DBS,$DBU,$DBP,$DBN);
        if($con->connect_error) {
            echo "Error : ".$con->connect_error;
        }
        else {
            $sql = "CREAT DATABASE '$DBN'";
            $sql .= "CREATE TABLE options (sitename VARCHAR(30),adminUser VARCHAR(30),adminPass VARCHAR(30),reg_date TIMESTAMP);";
            $sql .= "CREATE TABLE users (ID int(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, userName VARCHAR(30),password VARCHAR(30),reg_date TIMESTAMP);";
            $sql .= "INSERT INTO '$DBN' (sitename,adminUser,adminPass) VALUES ($SN,$AU,$AP);";
            if($con->multi_query($sql) === true) {
                echo " Enjoy .. ! ";
            }
            else {
                echo "Error : ".$sql." : ".$con->error;
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

However, when I type a sample name for the database, I get this error:

```
Error : Unknown database 'name'
```

And when create a database manually and type the name of it in my form, get this error:

```
Error : CREAT DATABASE 'ex'CREATE TABLE options (sitename
VARCHAR(30),adminUser VARCHAR(30),adminPass VARCHAR(30),reg_date 
TIMESTAMP);CREATE TABLE users (ID int(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY
KEY, userName VARCHAR(30),password VARCHAR(30),reg_date     
TIMESTAMP);INSERT 
INTO 'ex' (sitename,adminUser,adminPass) VALUES (My Phone 
Book,admin,102030); : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the    
manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
syntax to use near 'CREAT DATABASE 'ex'CREATE TABLE options (sitename 
VARCHAR(30),adminUser VARCHAR(' at line 1
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You're trying to select the database `$DBN` (when creating the MySQLi-instance) before you have created it. You need to connect to MySQL without the database, create the database and then select it.

Comment: CREATE DATABASE not CREAT DATABASE

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I don't know with this code in fact I can make a database or select a available database?!! and if just I can select so how could i make a database?! thanks.

Comment: @denny  thank you but no change!

Comment: Check the manual: [`mysqli::__construct()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) and [`mysqli::select_db()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php)

Comment: Also, `INSERT INTO '$DBN'` is wrong. You need to insert into a table, not the database.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line to

```
$sql="CREATE DATABASE ". $DBN.";";
$sql.="CREATE TABLE options (sitename VARCHAR(30),adminUser VARCHAR(30),adminPass VARCHAR(30),reg_date TIMESTAMP);";
    $sql.="CREATE TABLE users (ID int(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, userName VARCHAR(30),password VARCHAR(30),reg_date TIMESTAMP);";
    $sql.="INSERT INTO  options  (sitename,adminUser,adminPass) VALUES ($SN,$AU,$AP);";
```

Comment: when I enter an available database name ,get this:Error : CREATE DATABASE ex;CREATE TABLE options (sitename VARCHAR(30),adminUser VARCHAR(30),adminPass VARCHAR(30),reg_date TIMESTAMP);CREATE TABLE users (ID int(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, userName VARCHAR(30),password VARCHAR(30),reg_date TIMESTAMP);INSERT INTO 'ex' (sitename,adminUser,adminPass) VALUES (My Phone Book,admin,102030); : Can't create database 'ex'; database exists

Comment: This won't work. There are more errors in his code, and in the database queries..

Comment: you were inserting in db changed it to table `option`

Comment: @MohammadTaghiGhandili - _"Can't create database 'ex'; database exists"_ - Kinda tells you the problem

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I'm confused! this code makes a database or selects a database?!! if makes so why I get error: its unknown name. and if selects ..?!

Comment: `new Mysqli($DBS,$DBU,$DBP,$DBN)` - The forth (`$DBN`) _selects_ the default database for your queries. `CREATE DATABASE $DBN` then tries to _create_ the database. If it doesn't exist, you will get an error trying to select it and If it _does_ exist, you you'll get an error trying to create it.

Comment: @NN Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database 'ex' in - Error : Unknown database 'ex'

Comment: @MagnusEriksson woow! thanks, :) so you indirectly want to say I should remove ($DBN) and let the sql query to maake it?!

Comment: If you remove `$DBN` from sql statement it would work. As you have already defined the database in `mysqli`

Comment: You should remove it when you create the database connection, then check if the database exists. If it does, select it with `$con->select_db($DBN)` and if it doesn't, create it and all the tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a database using a PHP variable, you need to use the `USE` statement. After that, you can create tables in MySQL.

Try the below code:

```
<?php
//ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');
if (isset($_POST['siteName'])) {
    $DBS = htmlspecialchars($_POST['databaseServer']);
    $DBN = htmlspecialchars($_POST['databaseName']);
    $DBU = htmlspecialchars($_POST['databaseUser']);
    $DBP = htmlspecialchars($_POST['databasePass']);
    $SN = htmlspecialchars($_POST['siteName']);
    $AU = htmlspecialchars($_POST['adminUser']);
    $AP = htmlspecialchars($_POST['adminPass']);
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        echo "Error : " . $con->connect_error;
    } else {
        $sql = "CREATE DATABASE $DBN";
        $con->query($sql);
        $con->query("use `$DBN`");
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE options (sitename VARCHAR(30),adminUser VARCHAR(30),
           adminPass VARCHAR(30),reg_date TIMESTAMP);";
        $con->query($sql);
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE users (ID int(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
            userName VARCHAR(30),password VARCHAR(30),reg_date TIMESTAMP);"
            $con->query($sql);
    }
    if ($con->query($sql) === true) {
        echo " Enjoy .. ! ";
    } else {
        echo "Error : " . $sql . " : " . $con->error;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved my problem with help of dear @MagnusEriksson  :
1. I should have removed @DBN from the code that makes connection to database
2. `sql="CREAT DATABASE '$DBN'";` should have changed to `sql="CREAT DATABASE $DBN";`